# How can i transform my function into variable for executing statement array

Tags: javascript, php, function, date

I don't know how to transform this code into a variable. I want to bind it inside a statement execute array. Here comes my code. I found this code to get the current date and your timezone.

I tried `$date = function() {}, echo $date();` but that didn't work. I tried to search for "Function to variable PHP" but all the examples didn't work. What am i missing here? And is this even possible?

So i want to do this to save it in the database. Can someone help me please. I am very thankfull for your help and time.

```
function showclienttime()
{
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['GMT_bias']))
    {
?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var Cookies = {};
            Cookies.create = function (name, value, days) {
                if (days) {
                    var date = new Date();
                    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
                }
                else {
                    var expires = "";
                }
                document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
                this[name] = value;
            }

            var now = new Date();
            Cookies.create("GMT_bias",now.getTimezoneOffset(),1);
            window.location = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>";
        </script>

        <?php

    }
    else {
      $fct_clientbias = $_COOKIE['GMT_bias'];
    }

    $fct_servertimedata = gettimeofday();
    $fct_servertime = $fct_servertimedata['sec'];
    $fct_serverbias = $fct_servertimedata['minuteswest'];
    $fct_totalbias = $fct_serverbias - $fct_clientbias;
    $fct_totalbias = $fct_totalbias * 60;
    $fct_clienttimestamp = $fct_servertime + $fct_totalbias;
    $fct_time = time();
    $fct_year = strftime("%Y", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    $fct_month = strftime("%M", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    $fct_day = strftime("%d", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    $fct_hour = strftime("%I", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    $fct_minute = strftime("%M", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    $fct_second = strftime("%S", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    $fct_am_pm = strftime("%p", $fct_clienttimestamp);
    echo $fct_month."/".$fct_day."/".$fct_year." ".$fct_hour.":".$fct_minute.":".$fct_second." ".$fct_am_pm."";
}




$order_number = random_int(100000000,999999999);

$query2 = "INSERT INTO order_history(register_user_id,order_date,order_number,order_history)
          VALUES (:register_user_id,:order_date,:order_number,:order_history)";

$statement2 = $connect->prepare($query2);
$statement2->execute(array(
':register_user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
':order_date' => $date,
':order_history' => $output,
':order_number' => $order_number
));
```

Comment: Which part is the function? I might return a value from the function and store it in a variable.

Comment: Whats your PHP version?

Comment: @showdev I had it included but i had to add a 'enter' for it to show. It begins by `function showclienttime()`

Comment: @slepic Just the latest one i think

Comment: @ slepic I looked it up and it is PHP version: 7.0.33

Comment: It's fixed, i forgot to put the closing semicolon on the closing bracket

Comment: But when executing the array this stay's empty `:order_date' => $date()`. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is called [anonymous function.](https://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Supported php Versions 5.3 +

```
<?php
$date= function() {
    return date('Y-m-d');
};
echo $date();
?>
```

Comment: I said in my post that that didnt work for me. I am getting an error on echoing the date.
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' ` How can i fix this

Comment: OOoooh, sorry, i forgot to put the closing semicolon on the bracket. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help you. :)

Comment: But when executing the array this stay's empty `:order_date' => $date()`. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: In $date function if you did not return any out put you will get empty data.

Comment: Where you define that function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195870/discussion-between-shivendra-singh-and-gester).